# Get one previous row in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have dataset

```
priority   start_date    end_date           user     value
1   22.02.2024 11:50    22.02.2024 11:50    login-1  10
1   22.02.2024 11:50    22.02.2024 11:51    login-1  15
3   22.02.2024 12:34    22.02.2024 14:50    login-1  100
2   22.02.2024 12:40    22.02.2024 12:40    login-1  10
1   22.02.2024 12:40    22.02.2024 12:53    login-1  5
2   22.02.2024 12:53    22.02.2024 12:53    login-1  15
1   22.02.2024 12:53    22.02.2024 13:18    login-1  20
3   22.02.2024 14:01    22.02.2024 14:15    login-2  60
2   22.02.2024 14:05    22.02.2024 14:05    login-2  10
2   22.02.2024 14:05    22.02.2024 14:05    login-2  10
1   22.02.2024 14:05    22.02.2024 14:10    login-2  10
2   22.02.2024 14:10    22.02.2024 14:10    login-2  10
```

how do I get this instead (column output)

```
priority   start_date    end_date           user     value  output
1   22.02.2024 11:50    22.02.2024 11:50    login-1  10     null
1   22.02.2024 11:50    22.02.2024 11:51    login-1  15     null
3   22.02.2024 12:34    22.02.2024 14:50    login-1  100    null
2   22.02.2024 12:40    22.02.2024 12:40    login-1  10     100
1   22.02.2024 12:40    22.02.2024 12:53    login-1  5      100
2   22.02.2024 12:53    22.02.2024 12:53    login-1  15     100
1   22.02.2024 12:53    22.02.2024 13:18    login-1  20     100
1   22.02.2024 14:51    22.02.2024 14:55    login-1  20     null
3   22.02.2024 14:01    22.02.2024 14:15    login-2  60     null
2   22.02.2024 14:05    22.02.2024 14:05    login-2  10     60
2   22.02.2024 14:05    22.02.2024 14:05    login-2  10     60
1   22.02.2024 14:05    22.02.2024 14:10    login-2  10     60
2   22.02.2024 14:10    22.02.2024 14:10    login-2  10     60
```

Conditions: i want take value from previous row with upper priority and start_date between start and end dates previous row.

I haven't query for this, because a don't know how its working.

Comment: recommend looking up LEAD and LAG functions

Comment: @Randy I studied them, but I couldn't apply them to my task :(

Comment: The row `1   22.02.2024 14:51    22.02.2024 14:55    login-1  20`  in the output does not appear in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t1
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT MAX(value) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY priority DESC) AS output
         FROM   table_name t2
         WHERE  t1.username   = t2.username
         AND    t2.start_date < t1.start_date
         AND    t2.end_date   > t1.start_date
       )
```

or, equivalently:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT t2.value AS output
         FROM   table_name t2
         WHERE  t1.username   = t2.username
         AND    t2.start_date < t1.start_date
         AND    t2.end_date   > t1.start_date
         ORDER BY priority DESC, value DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       )
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (priority, start_date, end_date, username, value) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '11:50' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '11:50' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-1',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '11:50' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '11:51' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-1',  15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '12:34' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:50' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-1', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '12:40' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '12:40' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-1',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '12:40' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '12:53' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-1',   5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '12:53' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '12:53' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-1',  15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '12:53' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '13:18' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-1',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:01' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:15' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-2',  60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:05' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:05' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-2',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:05' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:05' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-2',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:05' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-2',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, DATE '2024-02-22' + INTERVAL '14:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'login-2',  10 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| PRIORITY | START_DATE | END_DATE | USERNAME | VALUE | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-22 11:50:00 | 2024-02-22 11:50:00 | login-1 | 10 | *null* |
| 1 | 2024-02-22 11:50:00 | 2024-02-22 11:51:00 | login-1 | 15 | *null* |
| 3 | 2024-02-22 12:34:00 | 2024-02-22 14:50:00 | login-1 | 100 | *null* |
| 2 | 2024-02-22 12:40:00 | 2024-02-22 12:40:00 | login-1 | 10 | 100 |
| 1 | 2024-02-22 12:40:00 | 2024-02-22 12:53:00 | login-1 | 5 | 100 |
| 2 | 2024-02-22 12:53:00 | 2024-02-22 12:53:00 | login-1 | 15 | 100 |
| 1 | 2024-02-22 12:53:00 | 2024-02-22 13:18:00 | login-1 | 20 | 100 |
| 3 | 2024-02-22 14:01:00 | 2024-02-22 14:15:00 | login-2 | 60 | *null* |
| 2 | 2024-02-22 14:05:00 | 2024-02-22 14:05:00 | login-2 | 10 | 60 |
| 2 | 2024-02-22 14:05:00 | 2024-02-22 14:05:00 | login-2 | 10 | 60 |
| 1 | 2024-02-22 14:05:00 | 2024-02-22 14:10:00 | login-2 | 10 | 60 |
| 2 | 2024-02-22 14:10:00 | 2024-02-22 14:10:00 | login-2 | 10 | 60 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dgaf0yrF)